# Does it matter in sensorless BLDC motorcontrol if a motor is wired in delta or in wye configuration?

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, remote-control

Let's say I am designing an ESC for a sensorless BLDC RC motor and I don't know it is a wired in wye or delta, does it matter? Delta doesn't have a neutral point. So if I would want to use BEMF for determining the rotorposition it wouldn't be possible with delta wired since you need a neutral point to compare to.

If i look at BLDC motors they only list KV value's compatible with different battery voltages and what they don't mention if it is wired in wye or delta. So i gues it doens't matter? Or is that al RC types of BLDC motor are standard wye configured.

Answer (score 0):

It will affect the hardware if you want to use a sensorless BLDC scheme that uses the neutral on a wye motor. But most motors don't run the neutral out even if they are wye so most BLDC sensorless schemes are designed to not depend on that and thus work with all BLDC motor configurations.

Other than that, the control algorithm itself might need to be tuned to properly drive the motor, but this isn't specifically due to wye vs delta. Other differences in motor construction can require this too. It's also software, not hardware.

Comment: I mean if a motor is delta wired can I still like create a virtual neutral point. So I can compare it to the BEMF voltage generated in the remaning winding.

Comment: @LuukBenningshof That is one method, yes. That is one example of extra hardware required that would not be otherwise needed if the neutral were run out so if a design does not have that, then it can't be used with a design with no neutral.

Comment: On closer inspection you cant create a virtual neutral point on a delta wired 3-phase bldc motor. And bldc motors are never wired in delta config. Source: https://www.gohz.com/is-bldc-motor-star-connected-or-delta-connected

Comment: @LuukBenningshof Not true. Even your link about some motors being wye and some motors being delta. And you can create a virtual neutral on a delta because you can run sensorless BLDC drivers without need to know whether the BLDC is wye or delta wound. It doesn't matter form an external perspective.

Comment: The link says "With the characteristic of a BLDC in mind (Unidirectional current between any two phases, third phase remains idol), it can constructively be concluded that BLDC motors are ALWAYS star connected". But anyway so do you know if I can always use a 3 resistor network independent if it is wired in delta or wye?

Comment: @LuukBenningshof Yes, you can. The reasoning in that quote makes no sense. That article is wrong. Don't trust anything else you read on that page. Find a better reference.